# Nginx "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" when redirecting http-to-https + reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've configured nginx to forward HTTP to HTTPS. This works for everything except my reverse proxy websites (that are also configured in nginx).  I am getting the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in my web browser for reverse proxy sites.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Below, is the configuration I'm using in `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location / {
        root   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot";
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /files {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:89;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /photos {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:89/photos/;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you don't change an URI for the proxied requests you can as well use just `http://localhost:89;` in your second `location` block. Moreover these two location can be combined into the single `location ~ ^/(files|photos) { ... }` location. What I don't understand is where your SSL block (where you should have `listen 443 ssl;` directive)?

Comment: I was using stunnel to handle SSL.  After moving SSL over to nginx, I was able to avoid the "too many redirect messages".  Thank you for your tip to combine two locations into one.  It worked great!